# duplicating count or only looking for 1st statement

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

Link to sample spreadsheet: [attendance tracking](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_opMqa6FrA1VMM3QL2Bmbl4TVFAY49jD5FnzR4M2BPc/edit?usp=sharing)

The tab to look at is the AM Classes. We need a count of how many students attended a class/group that day but it must be unduplicated. Such as some students may attend more than one STEM class in a day, but how many they attend in one day doesn't matter. We only need it to count the student once for that day in the STEM group. What I have is two different options (G1027 & M1027) but they aren't working correctly. I hope this is making sense. Attendance will be entered in using set codes (different letters of the alphabet- A1027 shows the codes.) What we need to track and their codes are in column C at the bottom (the blue lines.) I was also given the suggestion of having the formula look through the cells in that days column and find anyone of those codes and if it did, to use another column that is filled with 1's to do the actual counting (Column F). I'm not sure how to set that up though.

Thank you so much for looking at this. We have struggled with this for a while now and have had it on google forums and no suggestions on how to fix it. Below is a snapshot showing a section of the sample sheet and what we are struggling with. Thanks again.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNuJU.png)

Comment: narrow down the problem in the question.  The link to your spreadsheet is information overload.  lots of data that is not pertinent to the problem at hand.  Can you provide a small portion of data that represents just the current issue you are dealing with.  (IE state which letters you are hunting for).  I do not know which letters belong to STEM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try G1027:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(G4:G1016,"(?i)[aglmpst]"))
```